# What is the difference between a .so and a .lo file?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I know a .so file is a shared library file similar to a .dll file in windows, but what about a .lo file?

Comment: See this: [tutor#1](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html) and this: [tutor#2](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html) **and this**: [tutor#0](https://www.google.ru/search?q=linux+shared+object+tutorial)

Answer (score 19):

```
.o  object         (contains compiled code)
.lo library object (contains information for building a .so with `libtool`)
.so shared object  (indeed compareable to a DLL)
.ko kernel object  (usually kernel modules)
```

See http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/libtool/libtool_8.html

Comment: It stated a little obscure. *.lo (and *.la) are text files that contains some definitions for libtool. If you don't use libtool - you don't need that. It just some hints bundled with corresponding *.o. *.la serves same purpose for *.so, which is a shared library.

Comment: @Cobra_fast, thanks for your answer. what do you mean by built into a .so.

Comment: He meant libtool could use this files to assemble *.so (and *.la too). libtool is a script designed to help shared libraries, but it's quite possible it just lost it's relevance nowadays - for my years in programming for linux, i've never seen necessity to use it.